# Does an exponential model fit my data?

Tags: statistics

I am measuring accumulation of a fluorescent-tagged protein at a particular location within a cell over time. In previous experiments that I have performed, I see a standard exponential distribution where the fluorescence intensity reaches a plateau, however in my current experiment, I see a distribution as shown below:

[image]

What is the best model to use for this data? Should I use two separate exponential models, one for the increase in intensity up to the peak and one for the decay phase, or is there another statistical model for this type of distribution. Thanks!

Comment: You should consider asking this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I have posted this question there as well.

Comment: You could try something like $$10+\left(a-\frac bx\right)e^{-c\,x^2}$$ (beginning with $a=b=60$ and $c=\dfrac 15\,$).

Comment: it looks like a body in rotation plots (from my undergrad days)..I have seen this many times but I can not be any more specific :(.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use spline regression. This is a relatively simple and accurate method that allows you to fit nonlinear behaviours such as that you are assessing. Splines are non parametric smoother formed by piece-wise polynomials, with pieces identified by a sequence of "knots" where pieces join smoothly. You can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) the basics of spline regression/interpolation, with some advices on how to perform an algorithm to find the interpolating "cubic" spline (most used in statistics).

Answer (score 1):

I my opinion you should search a model that fits your data, also you can use a model by parts because you have two behavior of your data very different.

Splines are good to fit because they can fit more or less anything but splines have a big problem, you lose the physical  meaning of the model. So in my opinion search in the literature a model can be the best option.

P.S : sorry for my english.